# SQL Diff of Whole Date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to devise a query that will group records by date. I have records that represent events that have occurred. If events occurred on the same section and within 50ms of each other, they should be grouped. The important part of my table looks like this:

```
ID | sectionID | eventDateTime | ...
```

I am thinking I would want to group by `sectionID` and `eventDateTime` (a `sectionID` will span IDs) and use a having clause to define my time grouping constraints. I also think this might not be possible with a query. I saw `DATEDIFF()`, but that only does calculations on a single component of the dates. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would you expect when you have 10 records within 10ms of each other? Should these all be grouped together or should there be two groups?

Comment: In practice, this won't happen, so they should be grouped together.

Comment: Datediff is fine - it finds difference of whole dates, just in units what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something akin to the following:

```
With [Events] As
    (
    Select 1 As Id, 5 As SectionId, Cast('2011-05-04 23:59:59.950' As DateTime) As EventDateTime
    Union All Select 2, 5, '2011-05-05 00:00:00.000'
    Union All Select 3, 5, '2011-05-05 00:00:00.049'
    )
    , TaggedData As
    (
    Select E1.Id, E1.sectionID
        , Cast(Coalesce(E2.EventDateTime, E1.EventDateTime) As Date) As TagEventDateTime
    From [Events] As E1
        Left Join [Events] As E2
            ON E2.sectionID = E1.sectionID
                And E2.Id <> E1.Id
                And E2.EventDateTime >= DateAdd(ms, -50, E1.EventDateTime)
                And E2.EventDateTime <= E1.EventDateTime
    )
Select SectionId, TagEventDateTime
From TaggedData
Group By SectionId, TagEventDateTime
```